# List WooCommerce Product Feed to Amazon Marketplace

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, woocommerce

I am using WordPress woocommerce. And using "List WooCommerce Product Feed to Amazon Marketplace" plugin for amazon listing from website. But in Report section I am getting below error:

```
Feed Processing Summary:
    Number of records processed     1
    Number of records successful        0

original-record-number  sku error-code  error-type  error-message
1   67715   8560    Error   SKU 67715, Missing Attributes standard_product_id. SKU 67715 doesn't match any ASINs. Make sure that all standard product ids (such as UPC, ISBN, EAN, or JAN codes) are correct. To create a new ASIN, include the following attributes: standard_product_id. Feed ID: 0. For more troubleshooting help, see http://sellercentral.amazon.com/gp/errorcode/200692370
```

I have added GTIN in product and my GTIN # is: 677151310900

Kindly help me to solve this problem, also suggest if any better idea for listing in amazon.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably, This kind of error occurs when any product is uploaded with different products information for any standard product ids like for your case having GTIN 677151310900 might be already listed by another seller with some other attributes values due to which they got failed to map those details with your products SKU information. In that case, they were asking to send only limited value such as you can just modify the products description, price, title and quantity rather than creating same products with others your custom data in Amazon catalog.
Thanks!